# use markdown module in Angular.js , it doesn't turn to the html element

Tags: angularjs, markdown

i use the markdown module in node.js , when i get some text from mongodb , i turn it to markdown :

```
newsList.forEach(function (news) {
    news.publishContent = markdown.toHTML(news.publishContent);
})
```

and send the data to the html via angular :

```
<p ng-bind="nl.publishContent" ng-show="!isEdit"></p>
```

but the result in the html page is

[image]

the html elements doesn't resolve into html elements , they are toString into the html , how to make it resolve into html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-bind-html` instead of `ng-bind`.

Comment: thank your for helping , when i change to ng-bind-html , the angular tell me "Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context." , how should i fix this problem?

Comment: I belive you have to sanitise your HTML before binding it to the paragraph using `$sce.HTML(delegate)` or `$sce.getTrustedHtml(value)` - more details here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce